# how to fix " illegal start of expression" error while declare method in java

Tags: java

I have declared a simple method inside a class that checks if a number is triangular or not but while declaring the method the compiler shows "illegal start of expression" error. Given Below is my code

```
            import java.util.*;
            import java.lang.*;
            import java.io.*;
            class Ideone
            {
                public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
                {

                    int n ;
                    Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in) ;
                    n = in.nextInt() ;
                    static boolean  isTriagular ()
                    {
                        int tn = 1 ;
                        while ( n <= tn  )
                        {
                            if ( tn == n ) 
                            {
                                System.out.println("yes" ) ;
                                System.exit(0) ;
                            }
                            tn += ( tn + 1 ) ;
                        }
                    }
                    // your code goes here
                }
            }
```

Main.java:14: error: illegal start of expression
        static boolean  isTriagular ()
        ^

Comment: by not nesting methods. move `isTriangular` outside of `main`.

Comment: Also, according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number) the nth triangular number can be found with `(n * (n + 1)) / 2`.

Answer (score 1):

You should move `isTriangular` outside of your main method and then call your method in your main method as shown below:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        int n ;
        Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in) ;
        n = in.nextInt() ;

        // your code goes here
        isTriagular();
    }

    static void isTriagular()
    {
        int tn = 1 ;
        while ( n <= tn  )
        {
            if ( tn == n ) 
            {
                System.out.println("yes" ) ;
                System.exit(0) ;
            }
            tn += ( tn + 1 ) ;
        }
    }
}
```

I changed the type of `isTriangular` to a `void` since you are exiting the entire program after printing something to the console. It would only need to be a boolean if you are returning a result from it to set equal to another variable.

An example of this is:

`boolean myResult = isTriangular();`

Comment: You need to pass `n` as a parameter to `isTriangular` and return a value from the function.

Answer (score 0):

you are declaring a function inside another function 
move `isTriangulaire()` declaration outside the `main()` function
you can call `isTriangulaire()` inside main after that